# Phonegap XML Reading

Tags: cordova, xml-parsing

Is it possible to give phone gap a link to an XML feed and then put that in the HTML itself?

I understand that there have been issues in the past regarding iphone apps connecting to online data sources... but was wondering whether this would still cause issues?

Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can write Javascript code that reads the XML feed and writes to a div. If you can do it in a local HTML5 file running in your desktop browser, which you should be able to do, then I'm not aware of any PhoneGap limitations that would disable that.